# Should I Reinstate My Business In Order To Dissolve It?

Tags: business, new-jersey

I have an LLC (in New Jersey) that I created about 8 years ago purely for tax purposes. I was self-employed at the time, and I thought by having an LLC, I could write off a bunch of expenses, and save on self-employment taxes. Anyway, I almost never used it, and it's just been sitting there, useless. I just got a certificate of revocation in the mail.

I just want to get rid of the business and be done with it. So the question is - should I:

1. Reinstate the business ($375 - $275 reinstatement fee + $100 annual fee) in order to dissolve it?
2. Don't take any action, just let it be revoked and leave it alone.
3. Something else?

I fear if I go route #2, I'll be penalized or somehow pay for bad standing in the future (or if I decided to create another business in the future, which is a possibility).

Ideally, I'd like to properly dissolve the business, but I don't want to pay $375 to do so.

Comment: Can you summarize any of what you know about NJ LLC law?  E.g., do they require annual fees or filings that you have not been making?  If it was already "revoked" what remains to be "dissolved?"